# Get the sum of double values in an ArrayList within the same String groups

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with two string values and a double value. I want to sum the double value in same string groups. Then assign them to a new List

```
public class DashboardOneData {

    private String diviName;
    private double fullHours;
    private String mLevel;

public DashboardOneData(String x, double y, String z){
    this.diviName= z;
    this.fullHours= y;
    this.mLevel= y;
  }

}
```

**This is a sample ArrayList.....**

```
List<DashboardOneData > items = new ArrayList<DashboardOneData >();
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 1.11 , "x"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 1.52 , "x"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("B", 2.22 , "m"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 3.12 , "m"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("B", 2.52 , "m"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("C", 2.85 , "y"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 2.22 , "y"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 3.12 , "y"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("B", 1.01 , "m"));
items.add(new DashboardOneData ("C", 2.85 , "y"));
```

**For example what i want is,**

```
sum String group A, x(double value)
sum String group A, m(double value)
sum String group A, y(double value)
sum String group B, x(double value)
sum String group B, m(double value)
sum String group B, y(double value)


A-x = 2.63
A-m = 3.12
B-m = 5.75
C-y = 5.70
```

Comment: Do your login in contructor itself

Comment: using getters and setters

Comment: And what have you tried to do that sum ? Not even a simple loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map` to collect the `DashboardOneData` instances having the same `diviName` and `mLevel`,

For example:

```
Map<String,DashboardOneData>
    map = items.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(d -> d.getDiviName() + "-" + d.getLevel(),
                                         Function.identity(),
                                         (d1,d2) -> new DashboardOneData (d1.getDiviName(),d1.getHours()+d2.getHours(),d1.getLevel())));
```

This will create a `Map` where the key is of the form "B-m" and the corresponding value is a `DashboardOneData` instance whose `fullHours` member contains the sum of `fullHours` of all input `DashboardOneData` instances having the same `diviName` and `mLevel`.

To add the values of the `Map` to a new `List`, all you need to do is:

```
List<DashboardOneData> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: How can i add new values to a new DashboardOneData ArrayList?

Comment: i am getting a error in android studio. i tried with couple of methods, nothing solve the problem.

**Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process.
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:**

Comment: @D.Madu I didn't know you were using Android Studio. You need Java 8 support. I'm not sure which Android Studio version/Android API level support Java 8.

Comment: ohhh...I am sorry my bad for not to inform you. can you give me solution for java 7. min api is 16.

Answer (score 1):

Best place to use a Map

```
class DashboardOneData {
    private String diviName;
    private double fullHours;
    private String mLevel;
    public String getDiviName() {
        return diviName;
    }
    public void setDiviName(String diviName) {
        this.diviName = diviName;
    }
    public double getFullHours() {
        return fullHours;
    }
    public void setFullHours(double fullHours) {
        this.fullHours = fullHours;
    }
    public String getmLevel() {
        return mLevel;
    }
    public void setmLevel(String mLevel) {
        this.mLevel = mLevel;
    }
    public DashboardOneData(String diviName, double fullHours, String mLevel) {
        super();
        this.diviName = diviName;
        this.fullHours = fullHours;
        this.mLevel = mLevel;
    }
}

public class AddListItemsBasedOnAttributes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Double> sumMap = new TreeMap<String, Double>();

        List<DashboardOneData> items = new ArrayList<DashboardOneData >();
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 1.11 , "x"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 1.52 , "x"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("B", 2.22 , "m"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 3.12 , "m"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("B", 2.52 , "m"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("C", 2.85 , "y"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 2.22 , "y"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("A", 3.12 , "y"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("B", 1.01 , "m"));
        items.add(new DashboardOneData ("C", 2.85 , "y"));

        Iterator<DashboardOneData> it = items.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            DashboardOneData dashboardOneData = it.next();
            String key = dashboardOneData.getDiviName() + "-" + dashboardOneData.getmLevel();
            if(sumMap.containsKey(key)) {
                double sum = sumMap.get(key);
                sum += dashboardOneData.getFullHours();
                sumMap.put(key, sum);
            }
            else {
                sumMap.put(key, dashboardOneData.getFullHours());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sumMap);
    }   
}
```

Declare a Map with key as String (combination of String attributes in `DashboardOneData`) and value as double. If key is present get the value add the new double value. Just like counting duplicates in a list.

Comment: can i use the sumMap like this??
**Map<ArrayList<DashboardOneData>, Double> sumMap = new TreeMap<ArrayList<DashboardOneData>, Double>();**

Because later i want both string values separately as well as the double value. put all three values to sumMap

Comment: i tried and i get *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList is not Comparable* error.
**Map<ArrayList<DashboardOneData>, Double> sumMap = new TreeMap<ArrayList<DashboardOneData>, Double>();
 String key = dashboardOneData.getDiviName() + "-" + dashboardOneData.getmLevel();
   if(sumMap.containsKey(key)) {
double sum = sumMap.get(key);
sum += dashboardOneData.getFullHours();
sumMap.put(dArray, sum);
 }else {
sumMap.put(dArray, dashboardOneData.getFullHours());}**

Comment: It would because your custom class **DashboardOneData** is not having any comparison mechanism. Classes like Integer, String, Double are implementing **Comparable** interface. Your class should be either **Comparable** or **Comparator** type. Blind rule - if you are adding objects of a class (which is not implementing any comparison mechanism) to a sorted collection like TreeSet, TreeMap it will throw ClassCastException saying I can't compare objects

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment, it is not required

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Set** it's a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. It models the mathematical set abstraction.

Try below code:

```
Set<DashboardOneData> newItems = new HashSet<DashboardOneData>();

for (DashboardOneData dashboardOneData : items) {
int double sum =0;
 for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    if(dashboardOneData.diviName.equals(items.get(i).diviName) && dashboardOneData.mLevel.equals(items.get(i).mLevel) ){
    sum=sum+dashboardOneData.fullHours;
    if(i==items.size()-1){
        newItems.add(dashboardOneData);
     }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: newItems is empty always